# Representing an expression containing ternary operator with the help of Tree ADT

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree, expression

I was building a tree to evaluate mathematical expressions containing unary and binary operators, constants and variables with the help of a binary tree.

But I am now facing issues in visualizing how to represent a ternary operation?
Can it be done through a binary tree?
If not do I have any better Data Structure to represent and evaluate the same?

Please comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using (or planning to use) a binary tree, you can make a node with three children by combining two nodes like this:

```
   \
    a
   / \
  /   b
 /   / \
1   2   3
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to allow constants/variables (nodes with 0 children), unary ops (nodes with 1 child), and binary ops (nodes with 2 children), I don't see what would be hard about having ternary ops (nodes with 3 children).  Perhaps we could give you a better answer if you explain why you can't visualize/implement a node with 3 children.

Comment: Till now, I was using a binary tree where for Unary operator it became an incomplete binary tree, for binary operators the non-leaf node is an operator and the leaf nodes are operands. What must I do to represent the two operators in a ternary operation? If I have a > b ? c : d                    Then where to put the second operator.

I don't know if I am thinking in a different direction, and most probably a wrong direction.

Comment: @dharam: `a` and `b` in my diagram could easily take the functions of `?` and `:`, e.g. `a`=`?`, `1`= subtree for `a>b`, `b`=`:`, `2`=`c`, `3`=`d`. If `1` evaluates to true, you evaluate `2`, else `3`.

Comment: Thank you.. I think I am exhausted now. The answer was right in front of my eyes and I didn't see it. Thanks a lot.